# Transport Phenomena, question on statement in Wikipedia article

Tags: complex-systems, transport-phenomena

The Wikipedia article on [Transport Phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_phenomena) contains the following statement:

> Transport phenomena encompass all agents of physical change in the universe. Moreover, they are considered to be fundamental building blocks which developed the universe, and which is responsible for the success of all life on earth.

This seems a somewhat grand and enthusiastic statement, but I suspect there is truth therein and would like to know more about its provenance, whence the rationale.
I burrowed into Wiki and heard back from the page author who said he was simply the editor of the material and did not know the origin of the statement.

Is there someone familiar with the subject who could point to a potential source?

Comment: Probably not unsurprisingly, that quote is copied everywhere online (cf. [this Brave search](https://search.brave.com/search?q=Transport+phenomena+encompass+all+agents+of+physical+change+in+the+universe)). Due to that, it might be hard to point to an original author.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article I see on [transport phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_phenomena) has a citation for the subsequent sentence to Plawsky's *Transport
Phenomena
Fundamentals* (2001), Section 1.1 of which [reads](https://books.google.com/books?id=m1vNBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22encompasses+all+agents+of+physical+change%22&source=bl&ots=yVM_dqXFeY&sig=ACfU3U3qokOehcwSFsApYgIPwYytg7xF9g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibhYqfk-r4AhWTmGoFHcvECNoQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22encompasses%20all%20agents%20of%20physical%20change%22&f=false)

> The scope of transport phenomena encompasses all agents of physical change, and transport processes are fundamental to the evolution of the universe and to the success of all life on
> Earth.

It appears that user Steve Quinn added this content to Wikipedia [in 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transport_phenomena&oldid=358984187), neglecting to enclose the direct quotation in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Qmechanic I found the quotation in Transport Phenomena Fundamentals, Fourth Edition by Joel L. Plawsky:

“The scope of transport phenomena encompasses all agents of physical change and transport processes are fundamental to the evolution of the universe and to the success of all life on Earth. As engineers, we can use the concepts embodied in transport phenomena to analyze the workings of natural systems [4] and to mimic those systems for the betterment of the environment, society, and the human condition.” (Section 1.1)

This introductory remark is fully explored down to the level of fundamental forces and well demonstrated in the remaining eight-hundred some pages. Somehow, I was able to download the PDF of the entire book and found it to be biblical in its scope, a truckload of tools for the engineer. And, I was able to track down the [4] footnote to:

[The Constructal Law of Design and Evolution in Nature (May 2010)
Adrian Bejan and Sylvie Lorente](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rstb.2009.0302)

“Abstract
Constructal theory is the view that (i) the generation of images of design (pattern, rhythm) in nature is a phenomenon of physics and (ii) this phenomenon is covered by a principle (the constructal law): ‘for a finite-size flow system to persist in time (to live) it must evolve such that it provides greater and greater access to the currents that flow through it’. This law is about the necessity of design to occur, and about the time direction of the phenomenon: the tape of the design evolution ‘movie’ runs such that existing configurations are replaced by globally easier flowing configurations. The constructal law has two useful sides: the prediction of natural phenomena and the strategic engineering of novel architectures, based on the constructal law, i.e. not by mimicking nature. We show that the emergence of scaling laws in inanimate (geophysical) flow systems is the same phenomenon as the emergence of allometric laws in animate (biological) flow systems. Examples are lung design, animal locomotion, vegetation, river basins, turbulent flow structure, self-lubrication and natural multi-scale porous media. This article outlines the place of the constructal law as a self-standing law in physics, which covers all the ad hoc (and contradictory) statements of optimality such as minimum entropy generation, maximum entropy generation, minimum flow resistance, maximum flow resistance, minimum time, minimum weight, uniform maximum stresses and characteristic organ sizes. Nature is configured to flow and move as a conglomerate of ‘engine and brake’ designs.”

This last sentence is a concept I have been seeking for quite some time.